# Nginx - How to add a Map Variable to a String

Tags: nginx

I have below configuration in my nginx.conf, however, for some reason, it doesn't recognise the $site_name as a variable

```
map $host $site_name {
  default example.com;
}
error_log  /var/www/vhosts/{$site_name}/httpdocs/var/logs/nginx/error.log error;
```

The error I get is

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/www/"$site_name"/httpdocs/var/logs/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such...irectory)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`error_log`](https://nginx.org/r/error_log) directive does not support the use of variables. So you don't.